# Excel 2010 link to Word bookmark

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, excel-2010, bookmarks

I'm trying to create a hyperlink to a Word bookmark from an Excel sheet in Office 2010. 
I've found a script in VBA, but it doesn't work with 2010 (It just freezes).
Anybody knows a workaround for this?

[This is the script that I found](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=761#instr)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It'll be easier to debug the script you've got if you post it!

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot the Link, its http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=761#instr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the document in the Insert Hyperlink (or Edit Hyperlink) dialog.

Click after the name of the document in the Address box, and enter # followed by the name of the bookmark.

Click OK and test the hyperlink.